# Log events parsed by Logstash end up in Loggly four times

Tags: logstash, loggly

My log events that are parsed by Logstash end up in Loggly four times. What could be causing this?

An example is, the line:

```
2014-11-05 01:52:55,485 PM PST [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

Looks like this in Loggly:
[image: Loggly screen grab]

My Logstash config file looks like:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "advcore-error"
    path => [ "/var/company/tomcat/logs/error/advcore-error.log"]
    sincedb_path => "$HOME/.sincedb"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "advcore-error" {
    grok {
      pattern => "%{DATE_US} %{TIME},%{DATA:offset} %{DATA:meridian} %{DATA:timezone} \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
      add_tag => "advcore-error"
    }
  }
}

output {
  loggly {
    codec => "plain"
    host => "logs-01.loggly.com"
    key => "<my-secret-key>"
    proto => "http"
    workers => 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but make sure you use the `date` filter to properly parse the events' timestamps in the `@timestamp` field.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

I had three other Logstash config files (four total), each of them with the same Loggly `output` blocks.

I didn't understand that an `output` block in a different config file would still pipe data from all config files.

It appears that the config files in a given Logstash `templates` directory (and possibly elsewhere?) effectively act as one big file.

Comment: Indeed. Logstash has a single log pipeline. Splitting the configuration into multiple files doesn't change this.